# Android assets, C, JNI

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, assets

How do you access an Android asset, such as a .txt file, from C with the JNI?

I'm trying "file:///android_asset/myFile.txt", and locally "myFile.txt" with a duplicate of myFile.txt in the jni folder with the C implementation file.

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409125/android-read-text-file-from-asset-folder-using-c-ndk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thing with assets is that you can't access them directly as files. This is because the assets are read directly from the APK. They're not unzipped to a given folder upon installation.

Starting from Android 2.3, there is a C API to access assets. Have a look at `<android/asset_manager.h>` and the `assetManager` field in `<android/native_activity.h>`. I've never used this though, and I'm not sure that you can use this asset manager API if you don't rely on a native activity. And anyway, this won't work on Android 2.2 and below.

So I see three options:

- you could extract the assets into some directory but this will take extra space
- you could (bunlde and) use something like libzip to read the assets from the APK in pure C.
- or, to avoid bundling an extra library, my personal preference is to read data in C, using JNI, from the Java `InputStream` object returned by `AssetManager.open()`. It takes a little code but it works great.

Comment: @olivierg have you an example on how to use JNI to use Inputstream from AssetManager?

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use the AssetManager C API, because you need to call a C/C++ library that requires a filename, a raw resource can be used, instead.

The only disadvantage is that it needs to be copied to your app's data (temp) dir at runtime.

### Place the File in res/raw

Place the file you want to read from native code in the `res/raw` dir.

### Make a Copy

At runtime, copy the file from `res/raw/myfile.xml` to the `data` dir:

```
File dstDir = getDir("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File myFile = new File(dstDir, "tmp_myfile.xml");
FileMgr.copyResource(getResources(), R.raw.my_file, myFile);
```

Now the filename to pass to your native code is `myFile.getAbsolutePath()`

### copyResource (rsrcId, dstFile)

```
public static File copyResource (Resources r, int rsrcId, File dstFile) throws IOException
{
    // load cascade file from application resources
    InputStream is =  r.openRawResource(rsrcId);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    is.close();
    os.close();

    return dstFile;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for making this thread live again after a long time. I read a file from `asset` folder and then wrote that file using `FileOutputStream`. My question is what the path of the file saved by `FileOutputStream`.