# Android read text file from asset folder using C (ndk)

Tags: c, encryption, android-ndk

I need to read text file from asset folder in android, by searching through internet I found that there is asset_manager api available from android 2.3 onwards. As I am targeting only tablet devices this is useful. But as I am not expert in C language I am not able to find any example on how to read/write files using file descriptor. I found many examples using FILE* (file pointers)

> My goal is to decrypt a js file from asset folder which is encrypted
>   using C (for securing the code), as js code is visible if end user
>   decompiled my apk. Because asset folder is inside zip file is it possible to do?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here is the code I used to read file from android assets folder using asset_manager ndk lib

```
    AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
    AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, (const char *) js, AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
    if (NULL == asset) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, NF_LOG_TAG, "_ASSET_NOT_FOUND_");
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }
    long size = AAsset_getLength(asset);
    char* buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*size);
    AAsset_read (asset,buffer,size);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, NF_LOG_TAG, buffer);
    AAsset_close(asset);
```

Added following line to my Android.mk

```
# for native asset manager
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid
```

And don't forget the include in source file

```
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
```

Comment: Great answer! Works for me in conjunction with Assimp to load 3D models. First, I load a file into memory like described above, then I pass the buffer to aiImportFileFromMemory

Comment: Can you help me figuring out where did you pass the file name ?

Comment: @Nishant Could you figure out how to pass the file name?

Comment: @re3el Sorry, I worked on it months ago and do not have access to the source codes.

Comment: #include <android/asset_manager_jni.h> for AAssetManager_fromJava

Answer (score 2):

Practically FILE* and 'int' descriptors are equivalent and fread/fwrite/fopen/fclose are the counterparts of open/close/read/write functions (the functions are *not* equivalent however, the latter are non-blocking).

To get 'int' from 'FILE*' you can use

```
int fileno(FILE* f);
```

in  header and to do the inverse you can use fdopen()

```
FILE *fdopen(int fd, const char *mode);
```

So either replace everything using the FILE* to int or just take one of the samples and insert this conversion code before the file reading.

Comment: OK. That has nothing to do with NDK actually, so if you post some C code here that you're having trouble with, the community will be able to help you better. Good luck with the coding :)

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty similar to regular fread/fseek functions.
Here's read function declaraton:

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

It reads from `fd` file descriptor into `buf` buffer `count` bytes. If you think about fread, then instead of:

```
fread(buf, count, size, file);
```

you will call:

```
read(fd, buf, count*size);
```

And that's it. It is so simple.

Seeking is also similar. Just look up the function declaration and read the argument names/description. It will be obvious.