# How to use fopen for JNI native functions when building .aar?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, fopen, aar

I’m trying to build a **.aar** library which contains native/C++ codes, so there is a jni folder at **src\main\jni** in the structure. One of the C++ function uses **fopen** to read a text file. The text file to be read is at **src\main\jni** along with other .cpp/.h as well. I’ve changed the file path for fopen to **"/data/data/[package name]/files/XXX.txt"** but it still fails. I’ve searched for some related posts but so far there’s no clear solution... thanks for any suggestions! (I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1)

Comment: The `src` folder will not be there at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the text file in the assets folder instead and use the AAssetManager API to read it at runtime. This is summarised in this post: [Android read text file from asset folder using C (ndk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409125/android-read-text-file-from-asset-folder-using-c-ndk)

Comment: Thanks! Where should I add the assets folder ?  **src\main\jni**  or  **src\main** ?

Comment: The assets folder, which will be available at runtime in your app, must be placed in src/main.

Comment: assets folder and AssetManager really works for me, thank you!