# imread works in a normal c++ program, but not in android with ndk native

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, ubuntu-16.04

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

#include <iostream>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_cppinandroid_MainActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                            jobject)
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread( "/home/<name>/a.png", 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        return env->NewStringUTF( "No data in image!" );
    } else
    {
        return env->NewStringUTF( "Data is in image" );
    }
}
```

That's what I have in Native Cpp part of the android project.
When I run the application with emulator, it always shows: `"No data in image!"` text.

I have compiled this program separately as a normal c++ opencv program. It is working perfectly fine.
I have given the absolute path too. Is that not enough?

Do  I have to write something in `build.gradle` also?

I am using Android studio, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android directories do not match Linux at all.

A good solution is to find your file through Java and pass the path to the file as a parameter to function Java_com_example_cppinandroid_MainActivity_stringFromJNI.

If your file is in public files, you can try "/sdcard/a.png" - but the path may vary between different android shells.

The possible solution from reading from public files:

Java:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + fileName);
if (f.exists()) {
foo(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

NDK:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_cppinandroid_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env,
                            jobject, jstring javaPath)
{
    const char* path = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaPath, 0);
    Mat image;
    image = imread( path, 1 );
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaPath, path );
    if ( !image.data )
    {
        return env->NewStringUTF( "No data in image!" );
    } else
    {
        return env->NewStringUTF( "Data is in image" );
    }
}
```

A better way to store a picture in assets and read AAssetManager like [Android read text file from asset folder using C (ndk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409125/android-read-text-file-from-asset-folder-using-c-ndk) or [How to properly pass an asset FileDescriptor to FFmpeg using JNI in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701029/how-to-properly-pass-an-asset-filedescriptor-to-ffmpeg-using-jni-in-android).

Comment: Thank you. So, you mean to say that we just cannot fetch the file directly by giving absolute address in C++ in Android. There isn't a way to do it?

Comment: You can get the absolute path to public files through Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(). This method is easier to debug.